# How Can Print a Visualization to Factorial of a Number with Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I know how to calculate the factorial of a number, but I want to display what's going on in memory as the method calls itself. So the factorial using recursion is as fallows

```
public static long factorial(int n) { 
    if (n == 1) return 1; 
    return n * factorial(n-1); 
}
```

and I want to achieve the following

```
factorial(5) 
   factorial(4) 
      factorial(3) 
         factorial(2) 
            factorial(1) 
               return 1 
            return 2*1 = 2 
         return 3*2 = 6 
      return 4*6 = 24 
   return 5*24 = 120
```

I've come to this point... I'm having trouble displaying the recursive return of the method (second part)

```
public static long factorial(int n) {   
    System.out.println("factorial("+n+")");
    if (n == 1) {
        System.out.println("return 1");
        return 1; 
    }       
    return n * factorial(n-1);      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing before you return:

```
public static long factorial(int n) {   
    System.out.println("factorial("+n+")");
    if (n <= 1) { // factorial(0) = factorial(1) = 1
        System.out.println("return 1");
        return 1; 
    }
    long fac = factorial(n-1);
    System.out.printf("return %d * %d = %d%n", n, fac, n * fac);
    return n * fac;      
}
```

To get the n spaces per line, you can add a helper function that takes in the current "depth" of the recursion and print n spaces accordingly.

```
// public function visible to the world
public static long factorial(int n) {   
    return factorial(5, 0);
} 

// helper function that takes in the current depth of 
// the recursion
private static long factorial(int n, int depth) {
    String spaces = repeat(' ', depth);
    System.out.print(spaces);
    System.out.println("factorial("+n+")");
    if (n <= 1) { // factorial(0) = factorial(1) = 1
        System.out.println(spaces + " return 1");
        return 1; 
    }

    long fac = factorial(n-1, depth + 1);
    System.out.print(spaces);
    System.out.printf("return %d * %d = %d%n", n, fac, n * fac);
    return n * fac;      
}

// helper function to create a String by repeating
// char c, n times.
private static String repeat(char c, int times) {
    char[] sequence = new char[times];
    Arrays.fill(sequence, c);
    return new String(sequence);
}
```

Comment: how can you add the spaces to every function call, as shown in the output?

Comment: @miatech I've added a second implementation where I take the spaces into consideration

Answer (score 2):

You can use the try{}finally{} blocks to do something "after" it was returned

```
public static long factorial(int n) {
    try {
        System.out.println("factorial(" + n + ")");
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println("return 1");
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("return " + n);
    }
}
```

Comment: would this not print twice if `n == 1` ?

Comment: Yes, the check should really be in the finally. Everything related to the print may be in there

Comment: Gets the job done, has no ill side effects, and is a complete and utter abuse of the `try...catch...finally` mechanism.   In other words, **a sweet hack** (;->).

Comment: @KevinAnderson As a particularly evil bonus, a `return` in a `finally` overrides the one that exited the protected block. In short, *`finally` always wins*.